# hover does not active when trying to see hidden qr code bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to clone a website and here is this website's link

https://shopee.vn/

as you can see in this picture, when I hover the mouse to the line name "tải ứng dụng"
it will show the QR code

[picture about problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgPpC.jpg)

my problem is, I want to use some extensions like page ruler redux to measure the QR code's size, but it disappear when I move the mouse to another position (I click to the hover at the force element state, but it still disappear).

I think that when I click to the hover at the force element state, it must show the QR code and it will not disappear ?

Could you please give me some way to make it display to measure it?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome/Edge Dev tools have a built-in measurement function, hopefully this gets what you want.

1. Right-click => Inspect element on the link, expand the div and click on the `:after` selector
2. Making sure the inspect element page is in focus (the last thing you clicked on), hover over the link
3. *With only the arrow keys on your keyboard*, navigate the element tree (up/down to move up and down, left/right to expand, enter if you want to copy a property, like the image url). As long as you don't click, the element stays up.

[image: dev tools]

Answer (score 0):

1. find the QR code element node by chrome devtools, as you can see in this picture, the `div` html which one has a classname be named `shopee-drawer__contents`

[picture about how to find element node name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUc9A.png)

2. In chrome devtools console, you can print it out or use document method to measure it.

For instanse `document.getElementByClass('shopee-drawer__contents').getBoundingClientRect()` 
[print out width & height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY6gw.png)

Comment: thank you for your comment. But when I code like your code in console, it said to me that I have this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBoundingClientRect') at <anonymous>:1:62 , So could you please see this error again ?

Comment: Yean, this is really a question, however, when you code in console , once the element node 'QR code' must be dispalyed，otherwise the error will be reported. Frist you need to position the cursor in console and make the 'QR code' appears in the browser together, then don't move the mouse and write the code using the keyboard.